# $\mathbf{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ vs $[-\infty, +\infty]$ in the Lebesgue integration theory

Tags: real-analysis, integration, soft-question, lebesgue-integral

$\def\Rbf{\mathbf{R}}$
By the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem), the real line $\mathbf{R}=(-\infty,+\infty)$ with the standard topology is not compact.

By the [Alexandroff extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension#The_Alexandroff_extension), one has the one-point compactification $\Rbf\cup\{\infty\}$, which is homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$. On the other hand, the [extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) $[-\infty,\infty]$ with the [order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Order_and_topological_properties) is compact; it is homeomorphic to the closed interval $[0,1]$.

When introducing the (abstract) Lebesgue integration theory, Rudin in his *[Real and Complex Analysis](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/real-and-complex-analysis-0)* uses the extended real line instead of $\Rbf\cup\{\infty\}$ for the *range* of measurable functions.

Is it just a matter of convention or are there any deep reasons that one should use one not the other?

Comment: I hardly ever see $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ in measure theory. I see $[-\infty,\infty]$ and $[0,\infty]$ mostly. The last set has a useful and intuitive arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it makes a big difference.  The key is *ordering*.

Lebesgue integration theory relies critically on having a good ordering on the range space of your functions, and on the space where the integral takes its values.  This can be seen in the very definition of the Lebesgue integral $\int f$ as the supremum of $\int g$ over all simple functions $g$ with $g \le f$.  The word "supremum" involves the ordering on the space where the integral takes its values, and the condition $g \le f$ involves the ordering on the range space.  You see it again in fundamental results like the monotone convergence theorem, Fatou's lemma, etc.

Now the ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ itself is pretty nice, what with the least upper bound property, but the extended reals are even nicer: in $[-\infty, \infty]$, every set has a least upper bound, every nondecreasing sequence converges, and so on.  This means we can avoid a lot of special cases when talking about functions with singularities or whose integrals are infinite.  The tradeoff is the algebra is less nice: $[-\infty, \infty]$ is no longer a field, and so we have to add some special cases for expressions like $0 \cdot \infty$ or $\infty + -\infty$.  But that's manageable.

By contrast, $\mathbb{R}$ together with an "unsigned infinity" would be totally unsuitable, as it has no good ordering at all: you don't want to say either $0 < \infty$ or $0 > \infty$, so the trichotomy axiom fails.  Then you have a problem with the definition of the integral: if you have a function $f$ that takes the value $\infty$ somewhere, you can't decide whether the simple function $g=0$ should be included in the supremum defining $\int f$.

Comment: Nice answer. I'm curious though, is there an integration theory that doesn't rely on orderings?

Comment: @rubikscube09: The Bochner integral comes to mind.  Though even there, you're indirectly using the fact that the norm on your Banach space takes its values in a space $\mathbb{R}$ that has a nice ordering.  I would venture to say that any theory that doesn't use the ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ at some level, isn't part of real analysis.

Comment: Yes, that's a good example. Another example I would have thought of would be integration w.r.t projection valued measures in spectral calculus. But that, of course, comes from a duality argument, which goes back to $\mathbb{R}$. Moral of the story: $\mathbb{R}$ is the cornerstone of analysis (as one might expect).

Answer (score 0):

$ [-\infty, \infty] \text{ and } \mathbb R\cup\{\infty\} $ are two completely different animals if you consider the topology. Now a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on a topological space is the smallest sigma algebra containing the open sets of that topological space.
So it has nothing to do with convention.
I could have used any other set as the *range* of a measurable function.
Recall the definition of a measurable function

> Suppose $(X,\Sigma)$ and $(X',\Sigma')$ are two measurable spaces, and suppose that the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma'$ is generated by the family of sets $\Pi$. Then $f : X \rightarrow X'$ is $\Sigma/\Sigma'$ measurable if (and only if, trivially) $f^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma$ for all $E \in \Pi$.

And for topological spaces we take the sigma algebras to be Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

You can talk about a measurable function from any measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$  to a topological space $Y$ by taking the Borel $\sigma$ algebra on $Y$ denoted by $\mathcal{B}(Y)$.

$\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ is obtained by "identifying" $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ of
$ [-\infty, \infty] $ .([reference](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~john/MT4522/Lectures/L16.html)).

So the family of measurable functions from any measure space $(X,\Sigma)$ to $(\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}))$ and that to $ ([-\infty, \infty],\mathcal{B}( [-\infty, \infty]))$ are different and that is because of the difference in topology (as the $\sigma$-algebra depends on topology here).

So the difference you must have understood by now is that $ [-\infty, \infty] $
has a natural ordering which $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ doesn't. And that helps us in deriving the Lebesgue integration theory.

Comment: It's true that they are topologically different, but I don't think that's as much an issue as the difference in their order structure.  See my answer.

Comment: Indeed, $[-\infty, \infty]$ and $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ are Borel isomorphic, so as measurable spaces they are the same.  There is no significant difference in the class of measurable functions you get, whether you use one or the other.  The issues arise when you want to define the integral of those functions.

Comment: Are they not different ? as measurable spaces? @NateEldredge

Comment: If I am going wrong somewhere please let me know, corrections are highly appreciated .

Comment: @Noobmathematician: The Borel sigma algebra contains $F_{\sigma}, G_{\delta}$ and many more such sets. So there is a possibility that differnt topologies give rise to the same Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: @Noobmathematician: [See this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432553/does-the-borel-sigma-algebra-define-the-topology-of-a-set) for a concrete example. This might pretty much be the case here as well.

Comment: @Noobmathematician: They are the same in the sense that there is a bijection $f : \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\} \to [-\infty, \infty]$ such that $f, f^{-1}$ are measurable, i.e. $B$ is Borel in $[-\infty, \infty]$ iff $f^{-1}(B)$ is Borel in $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$.  This is well known though a little annoying to prove; there is probably a similar question elsewhere on this site but I can't find one right now.  More generally, the same is true for any two uncountable Polish spaces.

Comment: @Bumblebee don't you think $S^1$ and $[0,1]$ produces different Borel $\sigma$ algebra?